# Multiple input file Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, executioncontext

I'm trying to develop a batch which can process a directory containing files with Spring Batch.
I looked at the **MultiResourcePartitioner** and tryied somethind like :

```
<job parent="loggerParent" id="importContractESTD" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="multiImportContractESTD">
        <batch:partition step="partitionImportContractESTD" partitioner="partitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="5" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner">
    <property name="keyName" value="inputfile" />
    <property name="resources" value="file:${import.contract.filePattern}" />
</bean>

<step id="partitionImportContractESTD" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <batch:job ref="importOneContractESTD" job-parameters-extractor="defaultJobParametersExtractor" />
</step>

<bean id="defaultJobParametersExtractor" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.DefaultJobParametersExtractor"
    scope="step" />

<!-- Job importContractESTD definition -->
<job parent="loggerParent" id="importOneContractESTD" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step parent="baseStep" id="initStep" next="calculateMD5">
        <tasklet ref="initTasklet" />
    </step>
    <step id="calculateMD5" next="importContract">
        <tasklet ref="md5Tasklet">
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="md5Tasklet" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <step id="importContract">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="contractReader" processor="contractProcessor" writer="contractWriter" commit-interval="${commit.interval}" />
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="contractProcessor" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<!-- Chunk definition : Contract ItemReader -->
<bean id="contractReader" class="com.sopra.banking.cirbe.acquisition.batch.AcquisitionFileReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext[inputfile]}" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean id="contractLineMappe" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
            <property name="tokenizers">
                <map>
                    <entry key="1*" value-ref="headerTokenizer" />
                    <entry key="2*" value-ref="contractTokenizer" />
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMappers">
                <map>
                    <entry key="1*" value-ref="headerMapper" />
                    <entry key="2*" value-ref="contractMapper" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- MD5 Tasklet -->
<bean id="md5Tasklet" class="com.sopra.banking.cirbe.acquisition.batch.AcquisitionMD5Tasklet">
    <property name="file" value="#{stepExecutionContext[inputfile]}" />
</bean>
```

But what I get is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'stepExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

What I'm looking for is a way to launch my job **importOneContractESTD** for each files contained in **file:${import.contract.filePattern}**. And each files is shared between the step **calculateMD5** (which puts me the processed file md5 into my jobContext) and the step **importContract** (which read the previous md5 from the jobContext to add it as data to each line processed by the contractProcessor)

If I only try to call importOneContractESTD with one file given as a parameter (eg replacing **#{stepExecutionContext[inputfile]}** for **${my.file}**), it works... But I want to try to use spring batch to manage my directory rather than my calling shell script...

Thanks for your ideas !

Answer (score 0):

Add scope="step" when you need to access stepExecutionContext

like here:

```
<bean id="md5Tasklet" class="com.sopra.banking.cirbe.acquisition.batch.AcquisitionMD5Tasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="file" value="#{stepExecutionContext[inputfile]}" />
</bean>
```

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning).

Comment: Thanks dimzak. I did, and quote are missing too : #{stepExecutionContext['inputfile']}. But now, what I get is FlowJob: [name=importContractESTD]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED], and of course, it doesn't process my files...

Comment: Try to remove the quotes because Spring Batch now checks for "'inputfile'" instead of "inputfile".Perhaps it's good to add a listener like [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html) , sect. 11.7 so the job will return failed when it doesn't find input files

Comment: Another thing that's worth looking: "file:${import.contract.filePattern}". Perhaps it would be better to be written like this:"file:${import.contract.filePattern}/*" to tell Spring Batch to process ALL files in that folder

Comment: Actually, import.contract.filePattern = /myDirectory/*.txt in my properties file. I left the quotes as you suggest and am going to put a listener to try to understand why there are no files to execute anything... Because the "stepJob" is not launched, that's why nothing is done. But why it's not launched, that's the question hehe. I added the property **<property name="keys" value="inputfile" />** which were missing to my jobParametersExtractor, but whatever I change doesn't seem to have any effect...

Comment: Hmmm, the Listener will help you identify if the problem is the input. From your first comment: jobParamExtractor didn't work well-inputfile was not found. Again, play with the quotes, I think they are not needed.